# GitHub Login and Enterprise URL issue

Tags: github

i used to connect to GIt from GIT win apps. now when i try connect it is asking to enter Enterprise URL. i really do not know what is Enterprise URL. so tell me what to enter for Enterprise URL. here is my screen shot.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/) is a self-hosted version of GitHub.

GitHub for Windows supports the regular cloud-based GitHub, in which case it knows to connect to `github.com`, as well as GitHub Enterprise, in which case it needs to know the server's address.

Normally, when logging into GitHub for Windows, there is a toggle right below the "log in" header (above the Username box) to switch between GitHub and GitHub Enterprise.

Assuming you want to connect to "regular" GitHub, try hitting the Cancel button, then going into your preferences (tools, Options...) and inspecting your accounts. Make sure that they are set to GitHub and not GitHub Enterprise.

If you actually want to connect to GitHub Enterprise, you will need to speak with your IT staff. The GitHub Enterprise URL could be just about anything.

Comment: This just happened to me on a forced update. Hitting "skip" bypassed it and still used my old login information without having to reenter it.

Answer (score 0):

A small hint:

Don't forget to add 'https://', else it is possible it does not recognize it as a valid Enterprise URL.